# Android maxLines and minLines attributes not working in XML

Tags: android, xml

I have an XML file which contains an `EditText` with these attributes:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_firstname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/view_margin_below"
        android:hint="@string/et_firstname"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:maxLines="1" />
```

Since `android:singleline` is deprecated, I looked for another option and I found these attributes, but they aren't working. I am allowed to enter as many newlines as I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like described in API for `minLines`and `maxLines` attribute, you have to use the attribute `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` too:

API:

> android:maxLines
>
> Makes the TextView be at most this many lines tall.
>   When used on an editable text, the inputType attribute's value must be
>   combined with the textMultiLine flag for the maxLines attribute to
>   apply.
>
> android:minLines
>
> Makes the TextView be at least this many lines tall. When used on an
>   editable text, the inputType attribute's value must be combined with
>   the textMultiLine flag for the minLines attribute to apply.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_firstname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/view_margin_below"
        android:hint="@string/et_firstname"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="1" />
```

So I guess, You just have to add this attribute.

### EDIT

To avoid misunderstandings: The behaviour of these attributes will allow to enter multiple lines, but it will be only shown one line. BUT, it´s scrollable, so if you put in some more lines, you can scroll up and down to see the other lines.

This is stated in API for `singleLine`. `minLines`and `maxLines` work similar:

> Constrains the text to a single horizontally scrolling line instead of
>   letting it wrap onto multiple lines

Comment: Meanwhile i figured out: the `inputType` attribute has to be `text`, not `textMultiLine` but you were close. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I made an Edit, because of the single line behaviour. I think it was a misunderstanding of the attributes. Admittetly, the API is a little bit misleading with the description "single line" .

Comment: `singleLine=true` has a different behaviour, than `lines=1`, but in simple cases they work similarly. Sometimes I have to use `singleLine` in addition.

Answer (score 2):

Since you defined both minLines and maxLines as 1, you may as well use lines="1" attribute.

Comment: Not working. I tried with only the `android:maxLines` attribute, same behaviour.

Comment: @FogarasiNorbert try lines attribute, not maxLines.

Comment: @FogarasiNorbert try removing both minLines and maxLines attributes then. I believe EditText should not allow second line by its default behavior.