# "maxLines" attribute doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my two EditText Username and Password and I'm using TextInputLayout

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tplUserName"
            style="@style/EditText_Style_1"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etUserName"
                style="@style/StandardEditTextStyle"
                android:hint="@string/un_login"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tplPassword"
            style="@style/EditText_Style_1"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
            android:hint="@string/pass_login">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                style="@style/EditText_Style_For_All"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my `style,EditText_Style_1` for TextInputLayout and EditText_Style_For_All for EditText.I set "maxLines" attribute to both styles but when I change next EditText(Password) by pressing "Enter" from android keyboard, it didn't work.I set singleLine and I work for me.You know this attribute is deprecated.

```
  <style name="EditText_Style_1">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/textColor</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/reg_margin_right</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/reg_margin_left</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-thin</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    </style>

    <style name="EditText_Style_For_All">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/edit_text_color</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/et_underline_color</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-thin</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Define android:inputType=" "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android maxLines and minLines attributes not working in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45042120/android-maxlines-and-minlines-attributes-not-working-in-xml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this set **`android:imeOptions="actionNext"`**  and also set **`android:inputType="text"`**
to Your **`EditText`**

> **Sample Code**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tplUserName"
            style="@style/EditText_Style_1"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etUserName"
                style="@style/StandardEditTextStyle"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="@string/un_login"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tplPassword"
            style="@style/EditText_Style_1"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
            android:hint="@string/pass_login">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                style="@style/EditText_Style_For_All"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: @LaWinKo happy to help you enjoy codding

Answer (score 0):

add `<item name="android:inputType">text</item>`also. it will not work without inputType

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etUserName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="5" 
    style="@style/StandardEditTextStyle"
    android:hint="@string/un_login"
/>
```

You just need to make sure you have the attribute "inputType" set. It doesn't work without this line.

```
android:inputType="text"
```